# Как запретить вход на сайт заблокированному пользователю

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста - как запретить вход на сайт если если у пользователя в БД пометка ,,блок,, ?
На странице выводилось - ваш аккаунт заблокирован

Comment: В коде входа добавьте проверку пометки, если она стоит — то вместо выполнения входа выдавать ошибку

Comment: проверку методом GET ? Не получается, таблица user, поле блок, если стоит 0 , вход разрешен, если стоит 1, тогда нет.

Comment: Вы лучше чем мы знаете, как и какими методами у вас реализован вход

Comment: через $_SESSION, логин и пароль проверяет, а поле блок надо указывать >1, пишет ошибку

Comment: Ау, если бы кто подсказал как прописать здесь  ``` and blok='".$blok."' ```  blok > 1 , а так всё работает

Comment: SELECT block FROM users WHERE login = $_SESSION['login']; if($row[0] == 1) {session_destroy(); exit(header(Location: /block.html));}